# Use VBA in some form to edit or create more VBA code for a file that will be distributed

Tags: vba, excel

So whilst I tried to make the title as clear as possible I will expand on it here.

I am trying to create a new macro, the data for that macro will come from Pastebin, this file would be distributed to many people in different countries. Thus my goal would be to be able to modify or update macros in one shape or form, I can do an easy test to check if there are updates but could not figure out how to modify a macro, I would happily create a new excel workbook temporarily that has these macros or possibly create a VBScript and that creates a macro, not sure of the best method to do this.

What I have done so far, form tons of searching how to programmatically moidfy macros is form the website [cpearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx)

However this needs the modification of security which has to be done one each computer that will use this file and that is just not a possibility.

If you need more clarification on the question feel free to drop a comment, (might reply tomorrow)

Any suggestions on how to modify or import macros or workarounds to achieve the desired effect would be amazing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like something I made a couple of years ago. (It's company property now so I can't redistribute it). Here is the general idea with PasteBin as source:

You can do this by creating a VBA-injector and placing the module name in the top of the Pastebin.

```
changesMadeDate|
Modulename1 updateDate1|
//your code here
|Modulename2 updateDate2|
//and so on
```

If you are working with just Modules, UserForms and Classes this is pretty doable but stay away from Worksheetcode because then you can't use the remove and add method but would instead have to rewrite the sheet code with SendKeys. (Unreliable)

What you need to do (using modules as example):

1. Create a Pastebin that contains all the modules as described above.
2. Create a methods to split the Pastebin data and save each module locally as moduleName + ".bas" using FSO.
3. Remove and add modules to the current project.

You can use this to also create a updateDate for each module and only update those that are newer. Just add a updateDate after Modulename in the Pastebin.

You can distribute just the VBA injector and everyone can use the modules after running the update. Also add changesMadeDate before the first module name in Pastebin and you can create a Workbook_open event that checks it to know if to run the update at all.

If you exceed the Pastebin char limit then just do:

```
ModuleName1 pastebinlink1|
ModuleName2 pastebinlink2|
```

Then go from there. Using a shared textfile would probably work better though.

Edit: You could also delete all but injector modules. Then add empty modules and use VBIDE.VBComponent.CodeModule then write into them, but I prefer the first way.